# Restrict access to classes and methods according to a predefined API

Tags: java, eclipse, api, frameworks

I have a Java project with multiple packages and multiple classes in each package. I want this project to be used as a library (better say framework in this case), offering certain functionalities. The framework will be used by other application (in a different Eclipse project).

How can I specify the classes and methods that I want to be available for other applications? I only want a few classes/methods to be part of the API. The rest of the implementated code should be hidden for the users.

PD: I don´t mean how to design the API, but how to organize the code or which access modifiers should I use.

Answer (score 2):

Well, unless you put all the code in one package, you're going to need to make public anything that gets shared between packages in your implementation.

Typically the way this problem is solved is by convention: provide documentation only for the API classes, and specify that any other classes in your JAR are not supported and may change at any time. This is what Sun did with java - the API ships under two separate package structures, java.whatever and com.sun.whatever. com.sun is not supported or documented, and you use those classes at your own risk.

Some API providers also like to ship two separate JARs, one of which is explicitly API and the other is explicitly support/implementation. This allows clients to only have a compile-time dependency on the API JAR, but a runtime dependency on both.

You should also strongly consider sealing your JAR(s) to prevent clients from putting classes in the same packages you're using and access your protected or package protected (default) members.

Answer (score 1):

Plain Java does not have good tools for dealing with this issue. In many cases, developers resort to a convention, such as not documenting certain classes/packages or naming them in a certain way. For instance "org.myframework" and "org.myframework.internal".

If you want something better, you should consider OSGi, which gives you control of what packages are exported from a bundle (a jar with extra metadata) and which ones you keep internal. You can even specify that a package should be exported, but only to the set of listed bundles. This can be useful in complex frameworks that span multiple bundles.

Comment: thanks, but I think OSGi exceeds the needs of this project. Nevertheless, your tips about naming conventions will be quite useful.