# How to prevent class access in Android library project AND use packages

Tags: java, android, jar, aar

I want to build an Android library project (jar/aar).

Say I have the main lib's class, named 'LibManager', and a utility class named 'LibUtil'.

And say it would make sense that the class will be in a different package from then LibManager, for example:

```
- com.test.mylib
   - main
      - LibManager.java
   - util
      - LibUtil.java
```

However, LibUtil is a util class that is relevant only for my library. So I do not want the project using my lib to have access to LibUtil.java.

I know I can place all of my lib's classes in the same package, and use the package scope (not specifying a scope), however, that misses out on organising the project with packages.

Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Same issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459320/restrict-access-to-classes-and-methods-according-to-a-predefined-api